# prevent default in IE

Tags: google-closure

I have event function like this:

```
 ###*
    Function to show all items   
 ###   
 showAllItemsToggle_: ( e ) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
    element = e.target
    ....
```

and it is on  tag with href="#"

and only in IE after fire this event is this event not prevented.
I think GC will solved problems like this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Older version of Internet Explorer, that is IE8 and below, do not support [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault). Instead, you will have to set the non-standard [`event.returnValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `false`:

```
e.returnValue = false;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks for replay. I think GC have it different. I  tried to set false even on e.event_.returnValue, but same result.